# Alternative to IF statement to apply dummy variables with time series data

Tags: r, if-statement

I am currently undertaking a project where I have to analyse government speech data (long story). What I am looking to do is create a dummy variable if a party is in government - which I have been able to do in a time period where only one party has been in government using this:

```
parl_data$government <-ifelse(parl_data$party=="PartyName",1,0)
```

However, within the full dataframe there are changes of the party in government. My data includes 'speech IDs' and by using the dates alongside, I can see where there were changes in government, and such what I would like to do is do the following:

```
IF (speech_ID <= x) {<br>
parl_data$government <-ifelse(parl_data$party=="PartyName",1,0)<br>
} else {<br>
parl_data$government <-ifelse(parl_data$party=="DifferentPartyName",1,0)<br>
}
```

As Im sure you know using IF returns the following error

> "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

how do I complete the above using other means?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If possible, could you share a sample dataset? Just 5 rows.

Comment: @Manu I've attached an example of the dataset, thanks!

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `datastep`.  It will allow you to create nested conditionals as deep as you want:

```
library(libr)

# Create sample data
parl_data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
speech_ID    party   
1            PartyName
2            DifferentPartyName 
6            DifferentPartyName 
7            PartyName')

# Run datastep
parl_data2 <- parl_data %>% 
  datastep({
  
    if (speech_ID <= 5) {
       government <-ifelse(party == "PartyName", 1, 0)
    } else {
       government <-ifelse(party == "DifferentPartyName", 1, 0)
    }
  
  })

# View results
parl_data2
#   speech_ID              party government
# 1         1          PartyName          1
# 2         2 DifferentPartyName          0
# 3         6 DifferentPartyName          1
# 4         7          PartyName          0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with a `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

# Create sample data
parl_data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
speech_ID    party   
1            PartyName
2            DifferentPartyName 
6            DifferentPartyName 
7            PartyName')



parl_data2 <- parl_data %>% 
  mutate(government = case_when(speech_ID <= 5 & party == "PartyName" ~ 1,
                                speech_ID <= 5 & party == "DifferentPartyName" ~ 0,
                                speech_ID > 5 & party == "PartyName" ~ 0,
                                speech_ID > 5 & party == "DifferentPartyName", 1))
         
parl_data2
#   speech_ID              party government
# 1         1          PartyName          1
# 2         2 DifferentPartyName          0
# 3         6 DifferentPartyName          1
# 4         7          PartyName          0
```